# Validate `DatabaseDef` in Slick

Tags: scala, slick

Given the following:

```
scala> Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
res0: Class[_] = class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

scala> import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._
```

I can define this invalid DB connection:

```
scala> val db = Database.forURL("jdbc:mysql://www.google.com:3306/person",
               "root", "")
db: slick.driver.MySQLDriver.backend.DatabaseDef = 
         slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef@18b5c395
```

I'd prefer to fail fast, i.e. attempt to validate this `db` and fail.

How can I do this?

Comment: unless the "slick" stuff is being lazy in the connection initialization, it will fail if it can't connect to the server  & db

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two aspects to this:

1. Setting a timeout; and
2. Using the `DatabaseDef` (`db`) to try to use the connection.

**1. Setting the Timeout**

From the MySQL [Driver/Datasource Class Names, URL Syntax and Configuration Properties for Connector/J page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html), the connection timeout for the MySQL driver defaults to "no timeout".

To change it, provide a configuration parameter as part of your JDBC URL:

```
val db = Database.forURL(
  "jdbc:mysql://www.google.com:3306/person?connectTimeout=500", 
  "root", 
  "")
```

The above sets the time out to 500 milliseconds.

**2. Connecting**

To force `db` to establish a connection we need to do something to the database. We could try to run a query, for example.  In the code below I'm using [DatabaseDef.createSession.con](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/bbf339df2545a32896a26b849a821aafaa66b897/slick/src/main/scala/slick/jdbc/JdbcBackend.scala#L38-L80) to establish a connection the the database:

```
import scala.util._
def test() = Try(db.createSession.conn) match { 
   case Success(con) => con.close
   case fail         => println("Didn't connect") 
}
```

A call to `test()` will block for, roughly, the amount of time set for `connectTimeout`.  That acts as a validation of your database connection parameters.